# Select from List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

**The problem has been solved, the code follows after the explanation of what it is trying to achieve.**

**The code should be able to retrieve the number of times the number repeats itself**

*Firstly, the Code is attempting to get a number from the user:
E.g: "221132"*

Afterwards, the user inputs a number and the program finds how many times that number is contained in his first input.

E.g: "2"  should return the number 3, since that is the number of times the number was used in the first input.

Note: I want to insert those into a `List<T>` and to count from there but:

- **I cannot to use the List(T).Count property.**
- **I Must use .FindAll to do it using LINQ**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        string InputNo = Console.ReadLine();

        List<char> result = InputNo.ToList();
        var strResult = result.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("Type the number you want to find and how many times it is repeated");
        string findOccurence = Console.ReadLine();

        var found = strResult.FindAll(p => p == findOccurence);

        int counterOfRepeats = 0;

        var intFound = found.ConvertAll(p => Convert.ToInt32(p));

        for (int i = 0; i < InputNo.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {

                counterOfRepeats++;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine(counterOfRepeats);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Note: This code counts the number of times the string repeats itself **without using .Count**

Answer (score 2):

I know that you said you can't use the `Count` property, what about Linq's `Count()` method?

```
var found = strResult.Count(p => p == findOccurence);
```

Answer (score 0):

FindAll returns a List.  You can get the number of items in the returned List by checking the Count property:

```
var found = strResult.FindAll(p => p== findOccurence).Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid the lambda expression:

```
int found = InputNo.ToList().FindAll(findOccurence[0].Equals).Count;
```